# microsoft bot framework - skype for business - error

Tags: botframework, skype-for-business

I am using Microsoft Botframework to publish a bot (Channel Registration). When I try enabling the channels , I see the bot to be working in Slack , Skype, MS Teams & Web chat . However (despite following the steps to enable bot in SFB) I could not get the bot working in Skype for Business. I keep getting the error.

> "Sorry, we ran into a problem at our end."

Neither do I see any log to debug.

Waited more than 24 hrs to ensure it is not the sync issue. But issue still remains. Any help appreciated !!

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear with the error as to from which end it is being thrown.
I need you to follow the below steps:

- Publish Bot in azure as an app service, through VS if you are coding through c#.
- Create a "Bot channel registration" in azure and connect the above app service and Bot channel registration(simple use the URL of the app service append it with /api/messages and insert the same as messaging endpoint in Bot channel registration).
- use the app id and app secret in bot solution and republish the app service.
- Inside Bot channel registration click on channel and enable it for Skype for business(you will find your BOT in SFB using the credentials you have used to create the bot channel registration).

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working. What i noticed is the following

I faced the issue when I used the SIP URI as somebot@mydomain.com to register the bot in my tenant.

And i got it working when I used the SIP URI as somebot@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com.

Unsure on the reasoning though :)

And btw thanks @Tanmoy for your answer aswell !!